# Replace css file for Topsy wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Topsy plugin for wordpress, but i wnnat to customize with more option like change background.

how can i replace the topsy css file?

the css file is loaded after my css and use many !important and replace my customization.

tks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen different ways of including Topsy in Wordpress plugins, but it seems the latest version of the plugin loads a file called [topsy.js](http://cdn.topsy.com/topsy.js?init=topsyWidgetCreator), and this contains a function `loadCssFile`. If you place some Javascript code after this `script` tag that redefines `loadCssFile` as an empty function, the CSS will not get loaded.

Comment: You are right! but my question is exaclty how to redefines loadCssFile as an empty function, or cancel this action!

tks!

Comment: If you just add `<script type="text/javascript">loadCssFile = function() {};</script>` after the `wp_head()` call in your template, it should work. You can also try to append it in the `wp_head` hook, but this is more complicated.